# eigenvalues of a $X$-shaped matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By an antidiagonal matrix $J(a_1,\cdots a_n)$ in  $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, we mean a matrix $(a_{kl})$ where $a_{k,n+1-k}=a_k$ and the other entries are all zero.

Let us consider the diagonal matrix Diag$(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$.  Is there any approach to find the eigenvalues of the sum Diag$(b_1,\cdots,b_n)+J(a_1,\cdots a_n)$?

Comment: Any usual formula, such as Leibniz or Laplace, would pretty easily yield a general formula if applied iteratively.

Comment: Great, Any refrence?

Comment: The matrix is similar, via a permutation of basis vectors, to a direct sum of $2\times2$ matrices (followed by a $1\times1$ matrix if $n$ is odd). You are essentially asking how to find the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix. This shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @ABB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants for Leibniz and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace_expansion for Laplace